# MySQL error #1005 errno 150

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out why I'm getting an error here.

CURRENT TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE `Clients` (
  `ClientID` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Age` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Postcode` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`,`Age`,`Postcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Disclosure` (
  `ClientID` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Fname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Postcode` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `Offender` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Age` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Support` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Disclosure` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`,`Postcode`,`Age`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

trying to add foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE `FYP`.`Disclosure` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `client`
  FOREIGN KEY (`ClientID` , `Postcode` , `Age`)
  REFERENCES `FYP`.`Clients` (`ClientID` , `Postcode` , `Age`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I've tried using show status to see what the error is but I still cant figure it out.

```
 SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

returns:

> ------------------------ LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>   ------------------------ 171102 11:35:10 Error in foreign key constraint of table FYP/#sql-266_33b:
>
> FOREIGN KEY (`ClientID` , `Postcode` , `Age`)   REFERENCES
>   `FYP`.`Clients` (`ClientID` , `Postcode` , `Age`)   ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION   ON UPDATE CASCADE: Cannot find an index in the referenced
>   table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns, or
>   column types in the table and the referenced table do not match for
>   constraint. Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET
>   changed in tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in
>   old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables. See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an index on the referenced columns. The order of the columns in an index matter. In the clients table change the primary key to

```
(`ClientID`,`Postcode`,`Age`)
```

This should do it

```
ALTER TABLE clients DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`,`Postcode`,`Age`);
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed the issue =)